# PyCSW database schema fields

Tags: metadata, csw, pycsw

Does anyone know which specification the PyCSW database schema follows?

From which specification comes the database fields create by PyCSW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository schema of PyCSW may somehow correspond to ISO19115, so in fact its basically ISO19115. But it isn't really the goal of PyCSW to bind the repository schema strictly to one schema specification.

PyCSW handles metadata schema specifications (profiles) just like plain exchange formats, so its service interfaces support a great amount of different service types and profiles for different terms of usage. Someone is able to deliver INSPIRE compliant metadata and at the same time deliver simple metadata to a CKAN OpenData Portal for example. So PyCSW has kind of its own schema to store all the metadata elements it needs to produce different exchange formats and is simply mapping the fields to the attributes in every profile.

To see which standards are supported so far check out these doc ressources:

- Overview on its Features http://docs.pycsw.org/en/1.10.0/introduction.html#features
- Info on profile extension points http://docs.pycsw.org/en/1.10.0/profiles.html
- Profiles supported so far out of the box http://docs.pycsw.org/en/1.10.0/profiles.html#supported-profiles

BTW: OGC CS-W itself isn't strictly bound to a specific profile/metadata schema. Nevertheless, a lot of very basic (like 'title', 'abstract', etc...), i.e. dublin core metadata fields are contained in broader profiles also.

Comment: Vielen Dank Jürgen

Comment: You are welcome ;) ...would you please be so kind and accept this as an answer if their are no questions on this open anymore for you. Vielen Dank auch...